# Android: can't use Bluetooth in AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION

Tags: android, audio, soundmanager2

Earlier (in Android 6) when I do this when connected headset:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

I continue hear all sounds in my Bluetooth headset if it connected.

Now I do this, but after this I can't hear anything in headset.
All sounds are played through the regular speaker phone!

setBluetoothScoOn(true) not help.

What missing?

Comment: did u get an answer?

Comment: Also interrested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
 audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?